# ApplicationContext events never been thrown

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to have `ContextEventListener` on all ContextXXXEvent
I created a listener for each event type as following (the `ContextRefreshedEvent` is an Example):

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationRefreshedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    logger.info(getClass(), "Event source [{}]", event.getSource());
  }

}
```

Both `ContextRefreshedEvent` and `ContextClosedEvent` were caught and their listeners did the expected job.

I tried to do the same for `ContextStartedEvent` and `ContextClosedEvent` but both of these two events listeners were not caught.

The `event.getSource` printed (in the refreshed and closed events):

```
Event source [Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue May 09 10:07:51 IDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy]
```

Is there any difference between (started and stopped) and (refreshed and closed)?

Is it because my application context is `WebApplicationContext` (as the `event.getSource()` shows?)

Comment: refresh() is called implicitly during the creation of a concrete ApplicationContext, start is always explicit using the start() method

Comment: "I tried to do the same for ContextStartedEvent and ContextClosedEvent.....". You have already specified that you are able to successfully catch ContextClosedEvent. But in the next line you say that you were not able to catch the ContextClosedEvent. Can you please correct the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through spring code. I will discuss about ContextStartedEvent. Similar explanation can be given for stopped event.

**Explanation:**

ContextStartedEvent is emitted only from `start()` method of AbstractApplicationContext and nowhere. Since you are not able to catch the ContextStartedEvent, if we can know who calls or doesn't call this method we can find the answer.

In spring, applicationContext can be started in two ways. One, we explicitly call this method `start()` which will trigger the initialisation of beans in the context and rest of the context initialisation. The other way is for spring to take care of the context initialisation. In other words, we don't deal with context **start** and **stop** this way. Almost all of us unknowingly use the second way of initialisation. For example, you must be using xml files to load bean definitions which uses **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**. This is inherited from **AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext**.

Hence I think ContextStartedEvent and ContextStoppedEvent are emitted only if you start and stop (manage) the ApplicationContext manually. There are another set of ApplicationContext implementations which you can use to manage ApplicationContext on your own. I haven't tried them out personally. I will update the answer if I am successfully able to do this.

A similar explanation can be given to ContextStoppedEvent.

Update: This is inline with the definitions of the events provided in the spring docs (as well as the other answer to this question by @coolgirl)

Comment: @Marwan Jaber, do you consider this answer? or is there something else you are expecting?