# How To Call Method after DispatcherServlet Initialization completed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

How to Call Method After

> [DispatcherServlet] FrameworkServlet
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-1881e0df':
>   initialization completed in 4859 ms

I am creating Class that implement ApplicationListener

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextListener implements
    ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("ApplicationContext was initialized or refreshed: "
        + event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName());
  }
}
```

But onApplicationEvent still not fire, After Dispatcher Servlet Complete.

Any body know what's wrong with this?

Comment: How do you start you Application Context?

Comment: @FitrahEllyFirdaus can you please check the answers posted to see if anyone can be accepted? If not, can you please post what other information you need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ContextRefreshedEvent. ContextStartedEvent only works in specific cases where you start the applicationContext manually.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040750/3397712) for more info on the difference between ContextStartedEvent and ContextRefreshedEvent.

Comment: @FitrahEllyFirdaus are you able to get the events if you follow the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

According to spring documentation **ContextStartedEvent** works only with **ConfigurableApplicationContext** interface.

ContextStartedEvent is published when the ApplicationContext is started, using the start() method on the ConfigurableApplicationContext interface. "Started" here means that all Lifecycle beans receive an explicit start signal. Typically this signal is used to restart beans after an explicit stop, but it may also be used to start components that have not been configured for autostart , for example, components that have not already started on initialization.[Spring documentation on Standard and Custom Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)